# PHP remove anchor elements from shortcode before echoing

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I am using a shortcode that I need to be wrapped in an anchor tag when outputted to the dom however it already contains an anchor element which seems to be breaking the code. As I understand that an anchor element shouldn't be nested as this can cause unexpected results and isn't very logical.

Is it possible to remove the anchor elements from the shortcode before echoing to the dom. 
I will try to illustrate this with an example, excuse me if it is not clear. If 
`$shortCode = do_shortcode([example]);` where [example]'s content is

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  some code here
  <a href="http://example/url">Click me</a>
</div>
```

and this needs to be wrapped in an anchor tag

```
echo '<a href="http://desired-link-outside-shortcode">'.$shortCode.'</a>';
```

it should display in html dom like this:

```
<a href="http://desired-link-outside-shortcode">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    some code here
    <a href="http://example/url">Click me</a>
  </div>
</a>
```

however when echo'ed it appears like this in the dom:

```
<a href="http://desired-link-outside-shortcode">

</a>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    some code here
    <a href="http://example/url">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Hence me wanting to remove all anchor elements before echoing.

I have tried this (excuse the testing code) which didn't work as required:

```
$shortCode = do_shortcode([my_shortcode]);
$startFirstAchor = strpos($shortCode, '<a href');
$endFirstAchor = strpos($shortCode, '</a>') + 4;
$lengthFirst = $endFirstAchor - $startFirstAchor;
$endShortcode = strlen($shortCode);
$lengthSecond = $endShortcode - $endFirstAchor;

$firstPartCode = substr($shortCode, 0, $lengthFirst);
$secondPartCode = substr($shortCode, $endFirstAchor, $lengthSecond);
$refinedShortCode = $firstPartCode . $secondPartCode;

echo $refinedShortCode;
```

I am not a php professional so help or alternative methods to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: Why not using the resulting anchor from WPs `do_shortcode` instead?

Comment: Check this link i think it can be helful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an anchor overlay with absolute positioning to solve the problem. 
I adapted the solution from [How do I overlay an anchor on top of an image using dotnetnuke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330860/how-do-i-overlay-an-anchor-on-top-of-an-image-using-dotnetnuke)
.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(do_shortcode('[my_shortcode]'));

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node){
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This successfully removed the anchor elements, however the dom was still parsing the shortcode with the anchor element before it. For others note that `echo $dom->saveHTML();` is also required.